# kivy Equivalent to Tkinter after()

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

Changing the UI of my application from `Tkinter` to `Kivy` I cannot figure out the Kivy equivalent to Tkinter `.after()` function:

**Tkinter:**

```
self.after(5000, self.functionX)
```

**Kivy:**

```
?????
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Clock.schedule_once` is your friend !

```
Clock.schedule_once(function_x, 5.0) # like the 5000 ms in your example
```

Comment: Interesting however the difference is that after() seems to wait while Clock runs in continue.
My case:
 - I have an empty folder
 - Each time a file is created my app takes it and put it somewhere else

I will enhance my code in order to support the way clock works :)

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) object which allows you to schedule a callback just like the Tkinter `.after` method.

```
Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 0.5)
```

Comment: He needs schedule_once- schedule_interval call *my_callback* every 0.5 seconds and the **tk** after method will only call it once...